# DeleteIPAddress and AddIpAddress Problem

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, networking

i tried to write program adding ip address using this function

```
 
DWORD AddIPAddress(
  __in   IPAddr Address,
  __in   IPMask IpMask,
  __in   DWORD IfIndex,
  __out  PULONG NTEContext,
  __out  PULONG NTEInstance
);
```

I have added it but how can I delete it. **DeleteIPAddress** takes NTEContext as Parameter how can i get it in MSDN they write it is returned by AddIPAddress function but when i call it for the second time with the same ip address it returns an error 2. What to do?

I can view add ip addresses using Ipconfig command in cmd, may be there is some other method to view or delete it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366306%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> To use `DeleteIPAddress`, `AddIPAddress`
>   must first be called to get the handle
>   `NTEContext`. The previous procedure
>   assumes that `AddIPAddress` has already
>   been called somewhere in the code, and
>   `NTEContext` has been saved and remains
>   uncorrupted.

The lifetime of the added address is as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365801%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The `AddIPAddress` function is used to
>   add a new IPv4 address entry on a
>   local computer. The IPv4 address added
>   by the `AddIPAddress` function is not
>   persistent. The IPv4 address exists
>   only as long as the adapter object
>   exists. Restarting the computer
>   destroys the IPv4 address, as does
>   manually resetting the network
>   interface card (NIC). Also, certain
>   PnP events may destroy the address.

Comment: Sorry there's not a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetAdaptersInfo` in order to gain `IP_ADAPTER_INFO`.
`IP_ADDR_STRING` has a suitable context for `DeleteIPAddress` in `IP_ADAPTER_INFO`.